# zip list elements in different dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, zip, tuples

```
a=[['1','2'],['3','4']]
b=[['5','6'],['7','8']]
df14=pd.DataFrame({'key':a,'hi':b})
```

i want to add a 3rd column with tuples, where each list element from 'key' is matched with its list index in 'hi' -> e.g. that it looks like this.

```
       key    hi      tup
0   [1, 2]  [5, 6]  [(1,5),(2,6)]
1   [3, 4]  [7, 8]  [(3,7),(4,8)]
```

i know that i have to use the `zip` function, but i cant get thy syntax right.
i think it should be something like

```
for index,row in df14.iterrows():
   df14['tup']=df14.key.apply(lambda x: zip(x,df14.hi))
```

but this is somehow wrong

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here `iterrows` is not necessary, second row is modify for apply lambda function per row by `axis=1` and changed `d14.hi` for `x.hi` for return values per row of `hi` column:

```
df14['tup'] = df14.apply(lambda x: list(zip(x.key,x.hi)), axis=1)
print (df14)
      key      hi               tup
0  [1, 2]  [5, 6]  [(1, 5), (2, 6)]
1  [3, 4]  [7, 8]  [(3, 7), (4, 8)]
```